# Httpget with cookie android

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

I am trying to get a json string from a webservice. I have successfully login and saved a cookie in my sharepreference. the cookie is then passed to the getMyAdverts method with a url/path to retrieve the json data. Here is my method.

```
public static String getMyAdverts( String path, String cookie) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException{

    String link =path;
    System.out.println(link);
    String responseBody = null;

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(path);

    System.out.println("cookie "+cookie);
    httpget.addHeader("Cookie", cookie);


    System.out.println("executing request " + httpget.getURI());

    // Pass local context as a parameter
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

    System.out.println("response: "+response);

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    if(entity != null) {
         responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        System.out.println(responseBody);
    }
```

My problem is i don't get any response. Have i passed the cookie correctly or did i miss a step.  Here is my log.

```
11-14 11:15:05.246: W/System.err(24636): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-14 11:15:05.246: W/System.err(24636):    at application.util.Utils.getMyAdverts(Utils.java:352)
11-14 11:15:05.246: W/System.err(24636):    at application.app.applicationMenu$loadingTask.doInBackground(applicationMenu.java:478)
11-14 11:15:05.253: W/System.err(24636):    at application.app.applicationMenu$loadingTask.doInBackground(applicationMenu.java:1)
11-14 11:15:05.253: W/System.err(24636):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
11-14 11:15:05.253: W/System.err(24636):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-14 11:15:05.253: W/System.err(24636):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-14 11:15:05.253: V/SlidingMenu(24636): changing layerType. hardware? true
11-14 11:15:05.253: W/System.err(24636):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
11-14 11:15:05.253: W/System.err(24636):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-14 11:15:05.253: W/System.err(24636):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-14 11:15:05.253: W/System.err(24636):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

**UPDATE: METHOD 2 : THE COOKIE IS EXPIRED BUT THE COOKIE SHOULD EXPIRE ON SATURDAY 16 NOVEMBER HOW COME**

```
public static void cookieSession(String url, String cookie) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{
            String responseBody = null;
            CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
            BasicClientCookie stdCookie = new BasicClientCookie("Cookie",cookie);
            cookieStore.addCookie(stdCookie);
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE,
                    cookieStore);

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            httpGet.addHeader("Cookie", cookie);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext); 

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if(entity != null) {
                 responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                System.out.println(responseBody);
            }

        }
```